# User defined function - saving as addin

Tags: libreoffice

I created a macro in Libreoffice calc, which I named volume(). Now I want to use this function as a built-in function across all Calc. 
In MS Excel I can save it as an add-in. But here I am not finding a place to save the file. Can you please help? And what is the proper extension for add-in here?

Answer (score 0):

Store the macro under `My Macros` so that it can be used in any instance of Calc on your computer. If it is stored in a particular document, then it will work if you move the document to another computer, but it will not work in other documents.

Add-ins, on the other hand, are stored in zipped .oxt files known as add-ons or extensions. They require various XML files that you must create in order to define what it does. This makes it possible to distribute your code so that anyone can use it.

Documentation on creating add-ins is limited, and I don't have any good links using Basic. Your best bet is to find an extension with an add-in and unzip it to see how it works.

- [Official C++ documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Calc/Add-In/CompleteAddIn)
- [Example Java add-in](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/java/Spreadsheet/)
- [My description of a Python add-in](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/133794/how-to-use-develop-addins-in-calc/?answer=133870#post-id-133870).

If you want to create a Calc add-in but are not sure which language to use, I would recommend Python. That's because C++ and Java are needlessly complex for a simple add-in, and writing code in Basic outside of the LibreOffice IDE is less than ideal.